# How can I play a static mp3 file on static Javascript on a Django application?

Tags: javascript, django, mp3, django-staticfiles, collectstatic

In my Django Application, I am trying to play a mp3 file in a function in my javascript file. This JS file is loaded statically by command collectstatic from Django. I couldn't find a way to reference this mp3 file. Both are in the same folder in server-side. I'm thinking that I can only reference this file if it was upload in the page like other image, js or css file. There is a way to load this file to the browser in a Django application with its templates organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass the file to an HTML5 audio control using `static` like this:

```
<audio>
  <source src="{% static 'file.mp3' %}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Don't forget to `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top of your template.

Depending on whether these audio files change a lot it might be more appropriate to treat them as media files rather than static files. You can consult the Django [documentation on static and media files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/) for more information on the difference.

Comment: There is a way to use only JS, without any HTML tag?

Comment: Maybe something like `var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
audio.play();`